# Problemas con composer install

Tags: laravel, composer, phpstorm

Desde mi repositorio (bitbucket) he bajado un proyecto y lo estoy abriendo con **phpstorm**, tengo mis archivos `composer.json` y `composer.lock`, mi nuevo paso es poder realizar el composer install, para esto estoy utilizando este comando `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs` ya que trae poblemas mi versión de php, pero asi no tengo problemas de instalar.

Mi problema se genera una vez que terminar de instalar, mi proyecto se duplica en External Libraries - PHP - MI PROYECTO, el cual tengo en la raiz del proyecto, no se porque me sucede esto. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? Ayuda por favor.

Comment: Puedes compartir el archivo `composer.lock` por favor. Y en un comentario la imagen de la estructura de carpetas que te genera.

Comment: Y el composer.json también, por favor

Comment: Disculpen mi ignorancia, como puedo compartir los composer aquí?

Comment: Selecciona todo el contenido del archivo `composer.json`, cópialo al portapeles, presiona [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/354662/edit) en la pregunta, pégalo abajo de lo que ya tienes escrito, y guarda la edición.